# Not loading children nodes in layout javafx

Tags: spring, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to do a simple startup window for my application.

```
    ClassLoader cachingClassLoader = new MyClassLoader(FXMLLoader.getDefaultClassLoader());
    URL resource = MainApp.class
            .getResource("/startupWindow.fxml").toURI().toURL();
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(resource);
    loader.setClassLoader(cachingClassLoader);
    BorderPane rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

    scene = new Scene(rootLayout,512,384);

    this.primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    this.primaryStage.setTitle(TITLE);
    this.primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    this.primaryStage.show();

     //configuration main layout and add it to the stage
```

Unfortunately, after the start, application shows up startup window, however without any content. Throughout the loading of the main layout the startup window content is empty. Besides I had no exceptions.

I noticed that the problem with the content loading occurs when additional code is after the calling primaryStage.show(). And a content of layout is rendered at the end of additional code, for example:

```
    this.primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    this.primaryStage.show();

    Thread.sleep(2000L);
    // Content is displayed,( after 2 seconds ).
```

I have no idea how to make it work. Any advices will be helpful.

EDIT:

The issue I'm actually facing is create a startup window while loading Spring application context. I've been trying to create application context in separate Thread and it just hangs up with no exception occuring.

EDIT 2:

After some debugging I've found an exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'SomePresenter': Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-3
```

By the way, application follows MVP design pattern and Spring application context loads automatically views and presenters.

EDIT 3:

The piece of code where I create new thread is:

```
    Task loadingTask = new Task() {
    @Override
    protected ApplicationContext call() throws Exception {
        return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("./spring/application_context.xml");
    }
};

loadingTask.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
    context = (ApplicationContext)loadingTask.getValue();
    MainPresenter mainPresenter = (MainPresenter) context.getBean("MainPresenter");
    mainPresenter.getView().setPrimaryStage(primaryStage);
    scene = new Scene(mainPresenter.getView(), bounds.getWidth(), bounds.getHeight());
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/styles/styles.css").toExternalForm());
    this.primaryStage.setScene(scene);
});

new Thread(loadingTask).start();
```

Comment: You are trying to update the UI from your background thread. You need to separate the long-running, non-UI code (execute in a background thread) from the UI code (execute on the FX Application Thread). Show some of your threading code, including the line that causes the exception.

Comment: I have edited my question. Exception is directly caused by the code inside initialization of a custom control.

Comment: Clearly the application context is creating views on startup. Make the views (and presenters?) lazy-initialized (use `lazy-init="true"` in the `<bean>` definition). The views should be quick to create and this can be done on the FX Application Thread: only the model should be time-consuming to create, so have the application context create the model only at startup.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @James_D. I will try to use this solution.

Comment: It should be the case that you can actually create everything except the scene and stage from the background thread, then just create the scene and stage in the `onSucceeded` handler. As zenbeni says, that might not be true for anything but the very latest ea release.

Comment: There are some resources on zenjava about integrating JavaFX and Spring.  You have probably read them already, but if not that might prove useful to you. [JavaFX+FXML+Spring](http://www.zenjava.com/2011/10/23/javafx-2-0-fxml-and-spring/) and [porting first contact to Spring](http://www.zenjava.com/2012/02/20/porting-first-contact-to-spring/).

Comment: You should run Spring in JavaFX Application Thread, the overhead is very small, and it will be simpler to inject elements (beans/components) this way.

Answer (score 0):

The `start()` method is executed on the FX Application Thread, which is the thread responsible for rendering the UI and processing user input. It is also the only thread on which some actions are legal, such as accessing the state of nodes in the scene graph and creating `Scene`s and `Stage`s.

The problem is that you are executing code that blocks this thread, meaning that the UI doesn't have a chance to be rendered. If you have time-consuming (non-UI) code to execute, you should execute that in a separate thread, and then when that is complete schedule an update to happen to the UI on the FX Application thread.

The [`Task`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) class is designed for this use case.

So you can do something like this:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    primaryStage.setTitle(TITLE);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    Task<SomeDataType> startupTask = new Task<SomeDataType>() {
        @Override
        protected SomeDataType call() {
            SomeDataType result = ... ; // result of time-consuming operation
            return result ;
        }
    };

    startupTask.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
        // this is executed on the FX Application Thread
        SomeDataType result = startupTask.getValue();
        // update UI using result ...
    });

    new Thread(startupTask).start();
}
```

Comment: I've been trying to do that but it did not work. See my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you should check the EAP of JDK 1.8.0_40 as it enables you to build UI in background tasks as far as I understand what they are trying to do (out of JavaFX Application Thread):

See their JIRA:
https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-17716

Building UI in background tasks does make sense in some cases, especially with big FXML files as it is quite slow.

If does not solve your problem, you will have to check your Spring integration, are you using a custom FXMLLoader with a builder factory / controller factory? Does Spring run in a separate thread or in JavaFX Application Thread?

Comment: I'm using a custom FXMLLoader but I don't think it's a problem, because crucial part of GUI is created by code. Spring loads views and presenters (as I mentioned in my question) and is executed from separate thread. I will try out the JDK 1.8.0_40 and let you know more.